# Change Hippo repository path

Tags: hippocms

Help me please!
My web application running on the server with Ubunta. Jenkins takes the code shown on Bitbucket, and then sets it and manually loads the war files in the Tomcat, that's not deployed by cargo. The problem is in the fact that when I manually brush my folder with the web application, then the next time when i install, all data from the repository( settings, users) disappear. I tried to configure auto export in the console, but the button is not active and press on the checkbox in the Configuration/ Modules/Autoexport also does not help. On the local machine everything works, button is active and data exported to the folder 'bootstrap' to the folder with the project. But on the server is no folders with the project, it on the Bitbucket. And the inclusion of auto exports to the configuration pom.xml file in the cargo.run plugin too does not fit, that's Jenkins not deployed through the cargo, and loads the war files in the Tomcat. Is there another way to change the Hippo repository path?

Answer (score 2):

You can use -Drepo.path startup option. For more options please see this link:
[Repository Deployment Settings](http://www.onehippo.org/7_8/library/concepts/content-repository/repository-deployment-settings.html)

Comment: Likely to production it will not install Maven, how then to be?

Comment: you can add -Drepo.path option to your startup command (e.g. catalina.sh)

Answer (score 1):

Automatic export functionality is there to help you during development, so on your local machine. It is started when configuring it in the cargo.run profile. This profile is typically not used on production servers.

More info on Automatic Export can be found here: http://www.onehippo.org/7_8/library/development/automatic-export-add-on.html

Answer (score 0):

-Drepo.path = /path

-Drepo.Config = /repository.xml  -> for database config http://www.onehippo.org/7_7/library/deployment/configuring/configuring-hippo-7-for-mysql.html